# Why does overload ! operator need a const return

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

g++ 4.5.3 (cygwin)

```
class SlipDatum {
public:
   bool operator!();
   long operator~();
}

bool SlipDatum::operator!() { }
long SlipDatum::operator~() { }
```

Operator!() expects prototype:
    const bool operator!();

but operator~() works with no expectations. Any reaon why?

The compiler error is:

> SlipDatum.cpp:104:15: error: prototype for ‘const slip::BOOL slip::SlipDatum::operator!()’ does not match any in class
>   ‘slip::SlipDatum’ SlipDatum.h:15295:18: error: candidate is: bool
>   slip::SlipDatum::operator!()

Comment: What exactly is the error? (The actual error message could be very useful)

Comment: "Operator!() expects prototype: const bool operator!();" - what does that mean? There nothing in C++ that would require any `const` anywhere in the declaration of user-declared `!` operator. (BTW: you forgot a `;` after class definition).

Comment: The error message follows (I sincerely hope that I have the mini-Markdown format rules correct). There is a semi-colon in the code. The error message occurs during compilation and not execution, so method entry/exit is not an issue. The code body (with error checking) is about 16k SLOC and I hope to put it into to public domain, so it is available. code(SlipDatum.cpp:104:15: error: prototype for ‘const slip::BOOL slip::SlipDatum::operator!()’ does not match any in class ‘slip::SlipDatum’
SlipDatum.h:15295:18: error: candidate is: bool slip::SlipDatum::operator!())

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to figure out what you mean exactly, but in many cases missing `;` after class definition can lead to various bizarre and confusing error messages. I can't reproduce yours though in my version of GCC.

Anyway, add a `;` at the end of class definition.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SlipDatum {
public:
   bool operator!();
   long operator~();
};

bool SlipDatum::operator!() { return false; }
long SlipDatum::operator~() { return 0; }

int main() {
  SlipDatum unused;
}
```

this code compiles fine in [gcc 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/zNwVs2) [gcc 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/SuntyJ) and [gcc 4.7.2](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4lyofc%240)

Either you found a strange bug in gcc 4.5.3 (cygwin), or your problem is you failed to actually return from a function that expects a return value, or your question is badly formed, or your error is otherwise in the difference between your post and my answer.

Comment: Did you copy and paste his code? You added the missing semicolon at the end of the class definition.

Comment: SlipDatum.cpp:104:15: error: prototype for ‘const slip::BOOL slip::SlipDatum::operator!()’ does not match any in class ‘slip::SlipDatum’
SlipDatum.h:15295:18: error: candidate is: bool slip::SlipDatum::operator!()

Comment: `code`SlipDatum.cpp:104:15: error: prototype for ‘const slip::BOOL slip::SlipDatum::operator!()’ does not match any in class ‘slip::SlipDatum’
SlipDatum.h:15295:18: error: candidate is: bool slip::SlipDatum::operator!()

Comment: @arthur my code does not have anything named `slip`.  You need to take your code base and save a copy.  Then delete code that you think is unrelated to the problem but does not get in the way of compiling, and test if your problem still occurs.  Repeat until you have a single cpp file and no headers that fails to compile at that line, and the code is a few dozen lines long.  Then post it here.

Comment: Oh and search for the asshole using BOOL or who #defined bool to BOOL and shoot.

Comment: The code base is 12k SLOC with 4k SLOC in regression test code. The code is interlinked in a way as to make separating fragments of code into independent execution units difficult. In this case it may be simpler than most but, it is time consuming. Although your advise is good, I am frustrated at the time and effort it would take. I have built small test cases but, as above, from just coding statements which I hope generates the error. These efforts have failed, and the code doesn't work in practice but does work in my sample. The BOOL I regret, the slip is the namespace I created.